# Reversing a structed array with a recursive function

Tags: c, arrays, struct, structure, reverse

So i got this struct

```
typedef struct Sarray{
  int *items;
  int size;
}Tarray;
```

Considering an array like [1][2][3][4][5]

i built a function like this

```
void ArrayReverse (Tarray *a){
    int tmp,i;
    if (a->size<=1)
        return;
    tmp=(a->items[0]);
    (a->items[0])=(a->items[a->size]);
    (a->items[a->size])=tmp;
    a->size=a->size-1;

    ArrayReverse(a+1);
}
```

The  result is weird

0 2 3 4 5

The idea was to give the next address (a+1) so the a->items[0] would have been 2 in the second cycle.
What's wrong how could i implement it ?

Comment: if `size` is the number of elements, this line: `(a->items[0])=(a->items[a->size]);` performs improper assignment on the first function call. for example if size=5, you will assign items[5] which is out of bound

Comment: You should set a breakpoint in your function, step through it line-by-line and watch how the data changes with each instruction.  ***Use a debugger***

Comment: @mangusta you right  i should use it with items[a->size-1]

Comment: that's not the only problem though. `a+1` is useless for accessing the next element. you need to pass the value of `item`'s iterator

Comment: the problem is my function asks for a Tarray type so i cant really do that

Comment: Is it mandatory to use a recursive function?

Comment: @АндрійНемченко yep ofc sadly

Comment: with the data looking like: `[1][2][3][4][5]` and the struct having a pointer and a counter, the posted data and the struct do not match.  Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these statements

```
(a->items[0])=(a->items[a->size]);
(a->items[a->size])=tmp;
```

you access memory beyond the allocated array because the valid upper index is `a->size - 1`.

Instead of decreasing the data member `size` by one

```
a->size=a->size-1;
```

you have to decrease it by two.

```
a->size=a->size-2;
```

Moreover the function changes the values of data members `size` and `items` of the original object passed as an argument. So after exiting the function the state of the original object will be changed.

And this expression

```
a+1
```

does not make sense because you passed to the function a pointer to a single object of the type `Tarray`.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Sarray
{
    int *items;
    size_t size;
} Tarray;

void ArrayReverse ( Tarray *t )
{
    if ( ! ( t->size < 2 ) )
    {
        int tmp = t->items[0];
        t->items[0] = t->items[t->size - 1];
        t->items[t->size - 1] = tmp;

        t->size -= 2;
        ++t->items;

        ArrayReverse( t );

        t->size += 2;
        --t->items;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    Tarray t = { 0 };
    size_t n = 5;

    t.items = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( t.items != NULL ) t.size = n;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < t.size; i++ )
    {
        t.items[i] = ( int )( i + 1 );
    }

    ArrayReverse( &t );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < t.size; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", t.items[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( t.items );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: good idea. the possibility to increase `t->items` totally ran out of my sight - it's `int*` and I confused it with `int[ ]` which cannot be incremented for not being lvalue

Comment: @mangusta so why didn't you give +1 if you like it genuinely?

Comment: @snr fixed my mistake)

Comment: Your code is good. On the other hand i implemented another one with the counter i and it works well. I appreciate your alternative. You actually inspired me cuz i understood what was wrong with the old one . That (a+1) was pretty dumb i admit it XD

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the code is this one.

```
void ArrayReverse (Tarray *a,int i){
int tmp;
if(a->size <= a->lenght/2)
    return;
tmp=a->items[i];
a->items[i]=a->items[a->size-1];
a->items[a->size-1]=tmp;
a->size=a->size-1;
i++;
ArrayReverse(a,i);}
```

I changed the prototype of the function with the counter i.

Comment: I suggested that initially in the comments above and you told you're supposed to use Tarray only